# PowerShell script to update ContentType of existing records in Document Library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

we are using Document Library in SharePoint 2010 environment. there are about 200 document present in the document library which have been identified (based on location - England and employee type - FT) and now i have to change the content type of these 200 documents to a new content type 'New FT'. I'm using the below power shell code for the purpose -

```
$webUrl  = "http://www.site.com/sites/Library/"
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists["CURRENT FTE"]
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

    foreach($item in $listItems)
    {
        $lookup  = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue]$item["ROLE"];   
        $role = $lookup.LookupValue;

        $EMPTYPE  = $item["EMP TYPE"]

        $lookup4  = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue]$item["Location"];   
        $LOCATION = $lookup4.LookupValue;

        $ContentTypeName = $item.ContentType.Name
        $ContentTypeID = $item.ContentType.Id

         if ($LOCATION -eq "England") 
         {
            if($EMPTYPE -eq "FT")
            {   
                #CheckList - 1
                Write-Output  "ID - $($item.id) " 
                Write-Output  "Name - $($item.name)"
                Write-Output  "Role - $($role) "  
                Write-Output  "emptype - $($EMPTYPE) "
                Write-Output  "location - $($LOCATION) "
                Write-Output  "Content Type Name - $($ContentTypeName) "
                Write-Output  "Content Type ID - $($ContentTypeID) "
                Write-Output "  "

                $newct = $list.ContentTypes["New FT"]
                $newctid = $newct.ID

                    If (($newct -ne $null) -and ($newctid -ne $null))
                        {
                            $item["ContentTypeId"] = $newctid
                            $item.Update()

                            $newContentTypeName = $item.ContentType.Name
                            $newContentTypeID = $item.ContentType.Id

                            #CheckList - 2
                            Write-Output  "ID - $($item.id) " 
                            Write-Output  "Name - $($item.name)"
                            Write-Output  "Role - $($role) "  
                            Write-Output  "emptype - $($EMPTYPE) "
                            Write-Output  "location - $($LOCATION) "
                            Write-Output  "Content Type Name - $($newContentTypeName) "
                            Write-Output  "Content Type ID - $($newContentTypeID) "
                            Write-Output "  "
                            }



            }
        }

    }
```

Now the code identifies each document/record and then prints the details as listed on CheckList - 1, then i do an update and try to print the new updated values in CheckList - 2 - but the problem is the CheckList -2 doesn't print the updated content type and updated content type ID ($newContentTypeName, $newContentTypeID).

Am i doing some thing wrong here , Please advise ! (feel free to update the code if necessary)

Comment: Have you tried printing $item["ContentTypeId"] value after update? Is it correct? Also have you tried to get fresh item? Like this $updateItem = $list.GetItemById($item.ID); $updateItem.ContentType.Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with the help from 'Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets' comment above, I was able to make all the fields appear in the CheckList - 2. As per the comment I had to do the below -

```
 $updateItem = $list.GetItemById($item.ID); 
$contentTypeID = $updateItem.ContentType.Id
$contentTypeName = $updateItem.ContentType.Name
```